# Non-buffering of output of a program run in AppVeyor Windows environment

Tags: appveyor

As far as I can see the, stdout, output of a command in an AppVeyor jpb is buffered and only shows up in the log when the command finishes.
This is a bit of a nuisance as when the AppVeyor job is killed the output is lost ... ( :-( ).

Is there a way to show the output directly in the log file?

Comment: Each AppVeyor build happens on transient VM, which is being killed as build finished. Build output is being sent to central servers in real time and displayed in UI. The same way log file stored in AppVeyor is updated. There is no log file on build VM (other than specific build command can create). What is the bigger problem you solve? Why job is "killed"? Because of timeout?

Comment: Yes the job is killed after 1 hr (after approximately 50 minutes of "inactivity" i.e. in the endless loop or more likely waiting for a mouse click!!). The problem is that at some point in the debugging cycle not all the information appeared in the central log files.

Comment: Note that you can also [RDP](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/) to the build worker to debug. Environment variables from the build session are not available in RDP however (for security reasons), so you might need to re-set some.

Comment: Thanks, interesting posibility.